# Add custom tag to span in Jaeger when using in Istio service mesh

Tags: kubernetes, istio, jaeger

I want to add a custom tag in Jaeger span, I tried to install Istio on my Kubernetes cluster with this command:

```
istioctl install --set profile=demo --set meshConfig.accessLogFile=/dev/stdout --set meshConfig.outboundTrafficPolicy.mode=REGISTRY_ONLY -f .\tracing.yaml -y
```

and this is `tracing.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
spec:
  meshConfig:
    enableTracing: true
    defaultConfig:
      tracing:
        sampling: 100.0
        custom_tags:
          my_tag_header:
            header:
              name: test
              defaultValue: test
```

but there is no `test` tag in spans:
[image]
What should I do?

Comment: Which version of Istio are you using?

Comment: `istioctl version
client version: 1.11.2
control plane version: 1.11.2
data plane version: 1.11.2 (2 proxies)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Istio operator you have to initialize it first with

```text
istioctl operator init
```

By default Istio operator installs and watches only `istio-operator` namespace. If you want to specify another namespaces for it to watch (for example *default*), add `--watchedNamespaces` argument

```text
istioctl operator init --watchedNamespaces=default
```

With the operator installed, you can now create a mesh by deploying an `IstioOperator` resource. To install the Istio demo configuration profile using the operator, run the following command:

```text
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  namespace: istio-system
  name: example-istiocontrolplane
spec:
  profile: demo
EOF
```

Now, with the controller running, you can change the Istio configuration by editing or replacing the `IstioOperator` resource. The controller will detect the change and respond by updating the Istio installation correspondingly.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor I didn't pass `--watchedNamespaces` argument and when I added it, it worked.